# Android Compatible Portable A4 Printer

Tags: printer

TL;DR: I'm looking for a portable printer.

I am looking for a printer that can:

- Print A4 size paper
- Be carried in a backpack
- Connect to my Windows 10 laptop and Android phone (bluetooth preferred)
- < $150

A thermal printer is preferred, though any type will work. I have found the [Brother PocketJet](https://www.brother-usa.com/mobile/lp/pocketjet7/) series but they are out of my price range.

Comment: Do you need battery operating mode?

Comment: @neutrinus Not necessarily, but it is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to recommend the **[HP Deskjet 460c](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-Deskjet-460-Mobile-Inkjet-Printer-with-ac-adaptor-and-802-11g-printer-card-/162165020794?hash=item25c1c9d87a:g:ICoAAOSwVghXE7GO)**. This printer meets your requirements, though it is not a thermal printer. It [supports](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03722645#FAQ_HPePrintMobileApp) printing directly from Android via a wifi connection (no router needed AFAIK) using their [official free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.print&hl=en). It has a bluetooth receiver built in, but I'm not sure whether the app uses it. It comes with a battery.

Comment: It requires separate Bluetooth and WiFI network Cards. (Per Amazon; https://www.amazon.com/HP-Deskjet-Printer-C8150A-A2L/dp/B000B61X1S)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I linked you to an ebay listing that includes the wireless card for the same price.